# c++ cout << don't print '0' before decimal point

Tags: c++, decimal, number-formatting

I didn't find the solution to write decimal number inferior to 1 without the '0' before the decimal point.
I want to display numbers at this format : ".1", ".2", etc...

using :

```
std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setprecision(1) << std::fixed << number;
```

always give me formats like "0.1", "0.2", etc...

What do I wrong ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Convert it to a string, remove the 0, print the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert it to a string and use it for printing.
There is no way for a stream to print a floatingpoint without a leading zero, if there is one.

```
std::string getFloatWithoutLeadingZero(float val)
{
    //converting the number to a string
    //with your specified flags

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::setw(2) << std::setprecision(1);
    ss << std::fixed << val;
    std::string str = ss.str();

    if(val > 0.f && val < 1.f)
    {
        //Checking if we have no leading minus sign

        return str.substr(1, str.size()-1);
    }
    else if(val < 0.f && val > -1.f)
    {
        //Checking if we have a leading minus sign

        return "-" + str.substr(2, str.size()-1);
    }

    //The number simply hasn't a leading zero
    return str;
}
```

Try it [online](http://ideone.com/RStlSy)!

EDIT: Some solution you may like more would be a custom float type. e.g.

```
class MyFloat
{
public:
    MyFloat(float val = 0) : _val(val)
    {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyFloat& rhs)
    { os << MyFloat::noLeadingZero(rhs._val, os); }

private:
    static std::string noLeadingZero(float val, std::ostream& os)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss.copyfmt(os);
        ss << val;
        std::string str = ss.str();

        if(val > 0.f && val < 1.f)
            return str.substr(1, str.size()-1);
        else if(val < 0.f && val > -1.f)
            return "-" + str.substr(2, str.size()-1);

        return str;
    }
    float _val;
};
```

Try it [online](http://ideone.com/E1mPL4)!

Comment: Some improvements: (1) use `double`, (2) for negative value check if argument is negative, if so call self with -number and add hyphen, (3) for the rest check string result rather than original value, (4) do not use a `get` prefix (like `getsin`, `getcos`, `getsqrt`, ouch).

Comment: Thanks all,
This is what I feared, I hoped a nicer solution...
I will use the string conversion.

Answer (score 0):

In [`iomanip`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/) library, it seems no function to trim `0` before `cout`. You need to convert output to string.

Here is my solution:

```
double number=3.142, n; //n=3
char s[2];
sprintf (s, ".%d", int(modf(number, &n)*10)); 
                     //modf(number, &n)=0.142 s='.1'
cout << s;
```